# How to check unfinished function/process and block reload until it finish?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, server, pm2

i want able to check if my nodejs still have unfinished function/process when we want to restart/reload the server. I have done some googling and didnt found anything related to this.

**Trial and error:**
First i try to create new express from here https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html, then i install pm2 from here https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/, after that i modify my function to looks like this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(Date(), 'START')
  
  test1();

  test2();

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

async function test1() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(Date(), "test 1")
  }, parseToSecond(10));
}

async function test2(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(Date(), "test 2")
  }, parseToSecond(30));
}

function parseToSecond(second) {
  var milisecond = second * 1000
  return milisecond;
}
```

The result is when `test 1` printed out, i execute `pm2 reload`, and expecting the `test 2` to be printed out before the app reloaded.

My question is can we get the list of unfinished process and wait until they finish then reload/restart the app? Thank you